# About difference in difference with a lot of zero in outcome variable

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

Hi I use a difference in difference framework to study the policy effect. My outcome variable has a lot of zero, actually 75% are zero. My question is that how to interpret the aggregate effect based on the estimation from the regression. Is it okay if I calculate the aggregate effect by multiplying the estimation of the DiD coefficient and the total aggregate market size? Let's say I find the treatment effect is 3%, then I could multiply 3% by the total size in my sample, to estimate the aggregate effects. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Unless treatment was randomized or the treatment effect is constant (i.e., same for everyone), DID estimates the average effect for the treated units (ATET or ATT) rather than the average treatment effect for everyone (treated *and* untreated, aka ATE).

Multiplying by the total sample size assumes that the effect for the treated applies to everyone. That is a strong assumption and will require some justification.

Even if you are willing to do that, scaling by $N$ does not make sense to me if your effect is in percent. Say N=100. Is the aggregate product 300%? Perhaps you can spell out what you have in mind in more detail.

Comment: Say N=100 and ATT=30%. I believe OP is asking, can he/she interpolate that 30 events will have occurred out of 100 trials.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 I think the answer is most likely no. The aggregate effect is still 30%.

Comment: Let's say I get the DiD estimator to be 30%, which means that the outcome variable (y) increases by 30 percent, Can I use 30%  *  mean(pre-treatment y) to calculate the annual change of y induced by the policy? I actually get the number to be larger than the actual observed change in y, I don't understand what is wrong in this calculation.

Comment: The DID effect is relative to the counterfactual/unobserved untreated outcome for the treated units in the post period. Perhaps if you show your results, someone can help with the calculation.